# Saving data for two models, with infos coming from a 'multiple' <select> field

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm building a blog and I'm having a problem. I want to save a post and link it to many categories. This is my database:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/80b03.png (sorry, I can't embed the image here, I don't have 10 reputation)

What I want to do is saving a new Post, THEN saving many CategoriesPost. This is the code I use for my creation View:

```
echo $this->Form->select('CategoriesPost.category_id', $Categories, array(
    'multiple'  => true
));
```

My Post.php and Category.php have a HABTM relation with CategoriesPost, but I've tried many configs, even with a "hasMany through" relation, but had no luck. This, for reference, is the method I'm using in PostsController.php

```
public function admin_create() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Post->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true))) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Post salvato', 'default', array(), 'good');
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash('Errore nel salvataggio', 'default', array(), 'bad');
        }

        $this->loadModel('Category');
        $this->set('Categories', $this->Category->find('list', array(
            'fields'    => array('id', 'category')
        )));
    }
```

Every time I push that "Create" button, Cake saves my Post, but doesn't save any CategoriesPost or raises some SQL error because I'm saving a CategoriesPost without putting in a category_id or post_id. What should I do to save all of the infos in my DB? Should I change the structure of the $this->data array? This is, for reference, my $this->data array taken in Post::afterSave():

```
array(2) {
    ["CategoriesPost"]=>
    array(1) {
        ["category_id"]=>
        array(4) {
            [0]=> string(1) "3"
            [1]=> string(1) "4"
            [2]=> string(1) "5"
            [3]=> string(1) "6"
        }
    }
    ["Post"]=>
    array(4) {
        ["title"]=>string(1) "A"
        ["creation_date"]=> string(0) ""
        ["post"]=> string(1) "A"
        ["id"]=> string(3) "933"
    }
}
```

Help me, please :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do that.
The post_id in your categories_posts is obtained after you create the post record ($this->Post->save(), afterwards $this->Post->id will contain that id).
So atm when your doing saveAll you don't have the post id to create the categories_posts, you need to first create the post and then create all then entries in categories_posts in one big saveAll.

Which means you will have to build the data array you will be doing $this->CategoriesPost->saveAll($data) as a group of 2 pair array :

```
$data = array();
foreach($this->request->data['CategoriesPost']['category_id'] AS $category_id)
    $data[] = array(
        'post_id' => $this->Post->id,
        'category_id' => $category_id
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I wrote the same code, but I put it in Post::afterSave() method, so it didn't work. Your comment made me think about the problem and now I've moved this code to PostsController::admin_create(), solving the problem. Thank you very much :D

Comment: Actually the CakePHP ORM is capable of doing this internally on its own! **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm** | **http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcakephp%5D+save+habtm**